# Get a variable from an Entry in Python to create a Cloud Env

Tags: python, variables, get

hope you are ok, I'm new with python (less than 1 month) and I need some help here.

I have a script that runs OK when I set manually the variable in the script like one of these options:

```
   X= 1
```

or

```
   X= 2
```

or

```
   X=3
```

but when I want to get that variable from an Entry (box) I got this error.

```
    TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I've tried to put this into the script:

```
    X= IntVar()
    X= miEntry2.get()
```

also tried:

```
    X= StringVar()
    X= miEntry2.get()
```

and last

```
    X= IntVar()
    X= miEntry2.get()
    X= int(X)
```

and nothing works, because of that error. If I say X= 3 that runs perfectly. I guess I'm not able yet to change the data type (that's why I tried Int then String then Int again in different ways.

I got the results setting up manually the script but the idea is to get that info directly from an entry (miEntry2).

I'm using PyCharm in Mac.

Thanks for teaching us!

Comment: why do you create `X = IntVar()` if you don't use it later but you get value from `miEntry2`. If you create `X = IntVar()` then you would need `X.get()` to get value from `IntVar()`. But it seems you don't need `IntVar/StringVar` if you want to get value directly from `Entry`

Comment: if you want to get value directly from Entry then you need `X = int(miEntry2.get())`. But usually problem is `"when you use Entry.get()"` - if you use it before you run `mainloop()` then it gets empty string because it gets value before you see window and put text in Entry. You many need button which you press after puting text in entry and then button may run function which will use entry.get() to get value.